# PHP id and password verification

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, verification

I'm trying to do a simple login, which compares the input of the ID and password by the user with the data in the database

```
//getting the inputs
$checkid = $_POST["id"];

$checkpassword = md5($_POST["pass"]);

//getting the id and password of the id and password of the inputs
$query = "SELECT id, password FROM login WHERE id=$checkid AND password=$checkpassword";

$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$nres = mysqli_num_rows($res);

//$nres should be 0 if the user inputs the right id but the wrong password
//or viceversa, the only way that it $nres!=0 is that both inputs match the db, right?
if ($nres == 0) {
    header('Location: http://localhost:8888/login/login_fail.php');
    else
    header('Location: http://localhost:8888/profile/profile.php');
    exit();
```

it doesn't work, even if i put the right ID and the password that are on the database it will redirect to login_fail.php.
Note: it does work if i do it just with he ID and take out of the query " ,password" "AND password = $checkpassword". Help

Comment: Add quotes `"SELECT id, password FROM login WHERE id='$checkid' AND password='$checkpassword'"` and a sidenote: don't use `md5`, it's now insecure to use as password storage.

Comment: +1 and also note you are wide open to SQL injection attacks by not doing any processing on your POST variables.

Comment: You could also fix up your conditional statements' bracing. `if{...} else{...}`

Comment: Never use mysqli thing. But, i think this one will help you to check the error..


if (!mysqli_query($link, $query))  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));

Comment: hey @Fred-ii- thanks again man! What would you recommend to use as password storage?

Comment: and @JBES how do I do the processing on my POST variables? Thanks both! I'm still learning, forgive my noobness. :)

Comment: some docs: [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://ca1.php.net/fr/mysqli_real_escape_string) and [Safe Password Hashing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: You're welcome. Either [`bcrypt`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4795385/) or PHP's [`password()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) function. And [`see this article also`](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) and did my suggestion work? @LuisEgan

Comment: @MamaWalter has you started on that with mysqli_real_escape_string - `$checkid=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['id']);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok I'll use one of those! Yes, thanks man!

Comment: Ok and you're welcome. Did you want me to make my comment an answer so we can close the question? @LuisEgan

Comment: It's posted below @LuisEgan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add quotes to your variables:

```
"SELECT id, password FROM login WHERE id='$checkid' AND password='$checkpassword'"
                                         ^        ^              ^              ^
```

**Sidenote**: Don't use `md5`, it's now insecure to use as password storage.

For password storage, either use [`bcrypt`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4795385/) or PHP's [`password()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) function.

And see [`this article also`](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Also noted in comments by others, use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`:

```
$checkid=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the query:

```
$query = "SELECT id, password FROM login WHERE id='".$checkid."' AND password='".$checkpassword."'";
```

Comment: You need ' because you filed type in database will be char or varchar and nor int or float.